# If clauses not working

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I've created a little tool which pulls a price from another table according to what was sold. This works perfectly fine.
However I need to include a discount logic into that. There should be 3 ways to give a discount:

1. Enter discount manually (type in the value)
2. Waive 1, 2 or 3 times the monthly price
3. Discount up to 25% of the monthly price

All of the above can also waive the one-time Setup Fee (SuF).

Unfortunately the discount logic does not work and I can't find the reason why. Everything (price, setup fee etc.) gets added correctly to the record but not the discount. Also the values for **discountquantity, discount_percentage, waive_suf** are getting saved to the record as well. So the conditions to enter the respective if-clauses should be there.. What am I missing here? My guess is that I'm not returning the value correctly back to save it. I get no errors. The value for **discount** just does not get saved to the db.

Please find the explenations in the code below:

**sale.rb**

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
      ...
      before_save :discount
      ...

      def discount=(discount)

        #checks if manually typed discount is present and the discount value is not greater than the value defined in the user model (maxdiscount)
        if discount.present? && current_user.maxdiscount >= discount.to_d
          discount.to_s.gsub(",", ".") #need to transform comma into point
          discount = discount.to_d * quantity
          discount
        end

        #checks if discountquantity (1,2,3 months for free) is present
        if discountquantity.present? #discountquantity is the value (1,2,3) months for free
          discount = discountquantity * price
          discount
        end

        #checks if discount is 10%
        if discount_percentage = 10 #discount_percentage can be selected from the user in a dropdown
          discount = price * quantity * 0.90
          discount
        end

        #checks if discount is 25%
        if discount_percentage = 25
          discount = price * quantity * 0.75
          discount
        end

        #checks if SuF should be waived
        if waive_suf == true #can be selected from the user

            #if available the Setup fee gets pulled from another table
          if Warehouse.where(:product => self.product).where(:brand => self.order.brand).pluck(:suf).present? 
            suf = Warehouse.where(:product => self.product).where(:brand => self.order.brand).pluck(:suf).sum
            suf = suf.to_d * quantity
            suf
          end

          if setup.present? #can be entered manually
            setup = setup.gsub(",", ".")
            setup = setup.to_d * quantity
            setup
          end

          setup_fee = suf + setup #sums that up

        end

        self[:discount] = discount + setup_fee

      end #def discount=(discount)

    end
```

**Sales Schema (simplified)**

```
t.integer  "quantity",            default: 1
t.text     "comment"
t.decimal  "discount"
t.decimal  "price"
t.decimal  "setup"
t.integer  "discountquantity"
t.boolean  "waive_suf",           default: false
t.integer  "discount_percentage"
```

Many many thanks in advance!

Comment: Not too sure how you are saving the values in your model, but your code has some issues, for e.g.

`if discount_percentage = 10` if condition will always be true here as you have discount_percentage = 10 and not `==`

Comment: Thanks, didn't recognized that. But unfortunately it doesn't help :(

Answer (score 0):

Why are you doing `def discount=(discount)`, and then doing a `before_save :discount`, your `def discount=(discount)` will run when `Sale.new(discount: 'something')`, try changing to `def discount` instead.

```
class Sale < ActiveRecord::Base
  before_save :discount

  def discount
  end
end
```

Also just a code review tip, this method is very long and has a lot of branches as in if conditions, reduce it in to multiple methods.

Comment: I did, but this results now in a loop. I get the "app/models/sale.rb:106:in `discount'" like a 100 times in the log.

Comment: A little bit more info regarding how you are saving would be great

Comment: Hi there. What do you mean? I'm trying to calculate the discount, which can be entered by the user or through a dropdown. If the user enters the discount (discount.present?) then this should be used. If the user chooses 10 from the dropdown, then 10% should be used. There's pretty much nothing happening beside what i've posted. This code snippet actually works:   

`def discount=(discount)
    if discount.present?
      discount = discount.gsub(",", ".")
      self[:discount] = discount.to_d
    end
  end` 

And I've extended it with some if-clauses.

Comment: have you tried this self.discount = discount + setup_fee, Also I am not sure how Sale model is getting saving the data. More context is required

Comment: self.discount doesn't work either. The Sale itself gets saved through a form field. So nothing special here. The only value that doe snot get saved is the discount. And the discount should be calculated and saved in the model with the code above. Hope that helps.